# R- predict payment day (1-31)

Tags: r, prediction, model

I need to predict payment day of the month (1-31) for each client (I have at most 9 month of payments and on average is 5). I have both categorical variables and numerical. I tried to use rpart to do a regression tree (method='anova') but I'm not sure if it's using the nominal variables.

I also tried a regression (linear to start) and doesn't work good either, but it's better then the regression tree.

If I use a Weibull for this, will it mean that each client is going to have a parameter of shape and scale? what about the other variables? How can I insert them into the distribution?

So, what model would you recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try a randomForest.
It is similar to decision tree as easy of use.

Here you can find a good introduction
http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm